# Apache domainname instead of IP

Tags: http, dns, apache2, config, forward

I'm not sure this is even a question to be asked here, but I'll give it a shot anyway.

So I have an ubuntu server, and I recently purchased a domainname.

Now I have forwarded the domain to my IP, but whenever I reach the server, the browser shows the IP adress instead of the domain.

Is this something I should configure in Apache, or from godday (where I got the domainname)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you create the A record or CName record? This is going to map IP address with your domain name.

Comment: I don't think so, I only forwarded it to my IP. I'll give it a shot thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with checking your setup at Godaddy. What you probably need is an A entry.

The good news is that your setup seems to work since you get an answer from you server!

Perhaps this can help
http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/680/managing-dns-for-your-domain-names