# Redirect from webhotel to local apache webserver; Keep domainname

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, webserver, domain-name

So I have this website on a local machine. I also have a domain, let's call it mydomain.com. From mydomain.com there's a redirect setup to my local machine 
mydomain.com -> 192.168.0.1/mysite

But I want it to keep the domainname and hide my ip.
mydomain.com -> mydomain.com/site

I'm running Apache 2.4.7 on Ubuntu 14.04
I thought about modrewrite but after reading the documentation and some trial and errors I really got nothing. Is modrewrite the way to go?

I've put the modrewrite-stuff inside the 000-default.conf file in the Directory-tag. So I'm not using the .htaccess file because I read somewhere that it is not neccessary and also not the recommended way...?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution.
After reading the below thread a bit more thoroughly.
[Apache domainname instead of IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16005176/apache-domainname-instead-of-ip)

So all I did was creating a so called A record that pointed mydomain.com to my ip-address on the DNS on my webhotel and that solved the issue.